# Implementing cache system in Java Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications, caching

I worked with JPA (Eclipselink implementation) and Hibernate. As I understand these two have great caching systems.

I am interested in caching in a Web application and in order to better understand the process I'm trying to implement something on my own.

Sadly, I cannot find any in depth documentation about this subject. I'm interested in things like high scalability, sharing memory on different machines and other important theoretical matters. Is there any tutorial or open project I could check out?

Thank you!

*LE: * I want to cache DB information in POJOs just like JPA or Eclipselink

Comment: I'd suggest ehcache as a good source of info and starting point.

Comment: You are aware that you can tell the client to cache resources by setting an expiry date?  That might be a good place to start, as it will let you think about what you can cache and for how long.

Answer (score 1):

[Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) is a widely used [open-source](http://ehcache.org/code/source-repository) caching provider for Java with lots of features including replication, and works very well as a second-level cache for Hibernate.

Reading their [doc](http://ehcache.org/documentation/index) and browsing [their source](http://ehcache.org/code/source-repository) should give you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to cache static web pages, then using nginx or Apache is the way to go.  They'll server those files up faster then tomcat or jetty.  Pages you generate once per startup, you should consider generating those and then moving the page to nginx/Apache/etc as part of your deploy process.

If you're talking about pages that don't change that often, then you can create filter and use oscache, or other caching library to store the page in memory.  Make sure the filter you create is after whatever security you have, so your not serving cached pages to the world.

It's not covered much because you don't normally get enough return on the investment.  Most Web Aplication pages change to much to be good candidates for cacheing.

Comment: Thank you! However I'm interested in caching java objects which contain information retrieved from the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use memcached http://memcached.org/

there is a java client on memcached.

You can save the db object in memcached and achieve your purpose.

Ref: http://sacharya.com/using-memcached-with-java/